# Should I authenticate a user's password for every server request?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, security

I apologize if this may be common sense to some, but I'm still learning. I have an iOS app that syncs files to a web server. Once the user logs in on the device, he remains logged in unless he signs out. Currently, whenever the user initiates a server request, such as adding, updating, or deleting files, I only send the user's email and not the password to the server, since the user is already authenticated on the device.

Should I be sending the user's stored password each time he makes a request and have the server authenticate it before proceeding with the request? Why or why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should send a session identifier, rather than an email address.

The session identifier is a large number (128 bits is sufficient) chosen by a cryptographic random number generator when the user is successfully authenticated. It is set as a "cookie" in the user's web device and sent with each request over a secure channel (TLS).

Email addresses are public. You can only authenticate requests with secrets, like a password or a session identifier.

Comment: So each user has a single, once-generated, session identifier? Is this kind of like a unique ID for their server requests? Does it change with each request or is it a life-time identifier? What about a hashed password? Can I use that instead?

Comment: You generate a new session identifier each time they log in. Not sure what you are using for a server, but most will do this automatically for you. The key is that if the server generated a session id cookie *before* the user logged in, and sent that cookie over an insecure channel, you have to invalidate the session and create a new one at login. All authenticated requests must be performed over HTTPS.

Comment: So for example the Facebook iOS app..a user will typically remained logged in for months. How would they do it? They would use the same session ID for however many months the user has been logged in? Do they send an email or password? How do they lookup the user?

Comment: They can use the same session ID for as long as the session exists. While the session exists, the client sends the session ID to the server. The server looks up the session ID to see what user(s) it has authenticated to. (You may wish to invalidate such authentications on a password change.)

Comment: A scenario like that is not too much different than a typical web application with a shorter session. The main difference is that a small, unclustered web application with relatively short session expiration will often store the sessions in volatile memory. For longer-lived sessions like Facebook, they should be stored in some persistent storage. In either case, when a user logs out, the session is destroyed, and the identifier is no longer valid. When they log in again, a new session and identifier is created.

Comment: @pd40 Thanks! I'll add the OWASP link.

Comment: Oops, I thought that was a link to another question.

Comment: @erickson Sessions add no real value. Please see my answer as to why

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert, but until you get better answers here are a few tips:

- Each request should include some sort of "session identifier" to indicate it is part of the login session. This identifier should be impossible/difficult for an attacker to guess or to reuse. Often HTTP cookies are used for this, but you can include them in the URL.
- You should never send plaintext passwords over the network, as anyone sniffing the network will see them. Instead, you should send some sort of a hashed password or use a challenge-response protocol.

If you are using HTTPS, then you may not need to worry about this too much.  If it is unencrypted traffic, then you may want to "sign" each message with an additional hash value.

Answer (score 2):

Using an email address to identify a user means someone can possibly forge access to your service by using an existing users email address. As [Kristopher Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175/kristopher-johnson) suggests, using a session identifier avoids exposing credentials and is probably a good design choice.

The good people at [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) have a [session management cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) which is an excellent starting point for any design.

They do recommend using an existing framework for session management (Java EE, ASP.NET, PHP) if one is available.

Answer (score -2):

If you are going over SSL then sending username and password with every request is best. Why? Because its a simpler programming interface and because tokens add no real value. At some point to get the token you would have to send the credentials so what does it matter if you send the credentials every time or not? Nobody can decrypt SSL in a time worthy fashion. Now there could be other security loopholes like on the web server itself, but that has nothing to do with the transport from client to server (which is protected). Therefore, User/pass with every request is best.

And because its an iOS app, you can store the credentials in NSUserDefaults (which is sandboxed to your particular app and no other apps have access to it)

Please up vote and accept, the other answers are misleading

Now if it wasn't an iOS app and you had to store the credentials in a cookie instead of NSUserDefaults then OK, maybe you can make argument to use sessions. But other than that sessions are not worth the headache!

Comment: It's not a simpler programming interface on the server. Most web application containers assume use of a session identifier and automatically manage it for you. Any decent HTTP client library will provide similar, since it's a widely followed convention.

Comment: @erickson Yes actually it is simpler. Picture this. Client sends token. Server sends back token is invalid. Client has to request new token. That right there adds another unnecessary step.

Comment: @erickson can you explain any real benefit to using a token in this scenario? Perhaps I can learn something